# How to put class inside Html.Dropdownlist?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have this bizarre question, but it is bothering me a lot. I have this css class:

```
class="form-control"
```

And I need to use it in my DropDown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination)}), (SelectList)ViewBag.DropList)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are trying to set the `SelectedValue` of a `SelectList` within the `DropDownList` helper which is not possible.

You have to set the `SelectedValue` property when you create the `SelectList`. See following example.

```
ViewBag.DropList = new SelectList(new[]{
    new SelectListItem{ Text="one", Value="1"},
    new SelectListItem{ Text="two", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem{ Text="three", Value="3"}
    }, "Value", "Text", 2);
```

In the above code, I have set 2 as selected item when the `SelectList` is initialized. After that you can pass the `SelectList` and HTML attributes as below.

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", (SelectList)ViewBag.DropList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Thanks!

Solution:

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() {Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination)}), new{@class="form-control"})
```

Comment: Can you help me to edit my code for DropDownList in controller. I have post it in my question...

Comment: Is this `DropDownList` for `CustomTypes` ? Does `parameters.Destination` contains the selected value ?

Comment: I have solve it, I will post solution in your answer. Thanks man, your answer works :D

Comment: Did you post it ? I didn't delete anything.

Answer (score 1):

The last argument can be an object with html attributes, [see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ..., new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Could you post the latest version of the code? Does it match one of these signatures? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Error is this: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<AdminRole.Models.SpremenljivkeView>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, string, object)' has some invalid arguments